# AppEngine dev_appserver - urllib2.urlopen issue with localhost url

Tags: google-app-engine, urllib2, google-app-engine-python

### UPDATE

[App Engine SDK 1.9.24](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkReleaseNotes) was released on July 20, 2015, so if you're still experiencing this, you should be able to fix this simply by updating. See +jpatokal's answer below for an explanation of the exact problem and solution.

### Original Question

I have an application I'm working with and running into troubles when developing locally.

We have some shared code that checks an auth server for our apps using `urllib2.urlopen`. When I develop locally, I'm getting rejected with a 404 on my app that makes the request from AppEngine, but the request succeeds just fine from a terminal.

I have appengine running on port `localhost:8000`, and the auth server on `localhost:8001`

```
import urllib2

url = "http://localhost:8001/api/CheckAuthentication/?__client_id=dev&token=c7jl2y3smhzzqabhxnzrlyq5r5sdyjr8&username=amadison&__signature=6IXnj08bAnKoIBvJQUuBG8O1kBuBCWS8655s3DpBQIE="

try:
  r = urllib2.urlopen(url)
  print(r.geturl())
  print(r.read())
except urllib2.HTTPError as e:
  print("got error: {} - {}".format(e.code, e.reason))
```

which results in `got error: 404 - Not Found` from within AppEngine

It appears that AppEngine is adding the schema, host and port to the PATH portion of the url I'm trying to hit, as this is what I see on the auth server:

```
[02/Jul/2015 16:54:16] "GET http://localhost:8001/api/CheckAuthentication/?__client_id=dev&token=c7jl2y3smhzzqabhxnzrlyq5r5sdyjr8&username=amadison&__signature=6IXnj08bAnKoIBvJQUuBG8O1kBuBCWS8655s3DpBQIE= HTTP/1.1" 404 10146
```

and from the request header we can see the whole scheme and host and port are being passed along as part of the path (header pieces below):

```
 'HTTP_HOST': 'localhost:8001',
 'PATH_INFO': u'http://localhost:8001/api/CheckAuthentication/',
 'SERVER_PORT': '8001',
 'SERVER_PROTOCOL': 'HTTP/1.1',
```

Is there any way to not have the AppEngine Dev server hijack this request to localhost on a different port?  Or am I not misunderstanding what is happening? Everything works fine in production where our domains are different.

Thanks in advance for any assistance helping to point me in the right direction.

Comment: Where is AppEngine prepending a "/"?

Comment: I don't know for sure, and I could be misunderstanding what is happening... The `PATH_INFO` on the above request contains the "http://localhost:8001" when using urllib2.urlopen on AppEngine. The same call using urllib2 in a standard python shell results in `PATH_INFO` of just the `/api/CheckAuthentication/` like I'd expect. I'll re-phrase the question title

Comment: I'm getting the same issue. Seems to only happen with the url contains a port

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[App Engine SDK 1.9.24](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkReleaseNotes) was released on July 20, 2015, so if you're still experiencing this, you should be able to fix this simply by updating.

Here's a brief explanation of what happened.  Until 1.9.21, the SDK was formatting URL fetch requests with relative paths, like this:

```
GET /test/ HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:5000
```

In 1.9.22, to better support proxies, this changed to absolute paths:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/test/ HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:5000
```

Both formats are perfectly legal per the HTTP/1.1 spec, see [RFC 2616, section 5.1.2](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html).  However, while that spec dates to 1999, there are apparently quite a few HTTP request handlers that do not parse the absolute form correctly, instead just naively concatenating the path and the host together.

So in the interest of compatibility, the previous behavior has been restored.  (Unless you're using a proxy, in which case the RFC requires absolute paths.)

Comment: perfect, thank you for the explanation! I've updated the question above to point to your link and this answer.

Comment: ouch Stackoverflow - removing 15 points from me, right in the feeeeels ;)

Answer (score 4):

This is an annoying problem introduced by the `urlfetch_stub` implementation. I'm not sure what gcloud sdk version introduced it.

### I've fixed this by patching the gcloud SDK - until Google does.

*which means this answer will hopefully be irrelevant shortly*

1. Find and open `urlfetch_stub.py`, which can often be found at `~/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/urlfetch_stub.py`
2. Around line 380 (depends on version), find:

```py
full_path = urlparse.urlunsplit((protocol, host, path, query, ''))
```

and replace it with:

```
full_path = urlparse.urlunsplit(('', '', path, query, ''))
```

#### more info

You were correct in assuming the issue was a broken PATH_INFO header. The `full_path` here is being passed after the connection is made.

#### disclaimer

I may very easily have broken proxy requests with this patch. Because I expect google to fix it, I'm not going to go too crazy about it.

To be very clear **this bug is ONLY related to LOCAL app development - you won't see this on production.**

Comment: Thanks Josh... any idea if there is a bug already filed with the App Engine team? If not I can go ahead and file one

Comment: @Aaron I think Karl grabbed it, I posted it in the google group. Couldn't hurt to report twice? ;)
https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/google-appengine/MKhpW3L3iS0/m87CbsMufCwJ

Comment: thanks @josh.  Here is the bug link so hopefully others can star it too.  https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12123

Comment: So you are aware, the bug was marked WorksAsIntended. Turns out this a problem with the way many servers mishandle the HTTP spec. If you are using UWSGI http, putting it behind a real HTTP server like NGINX will solve the problem. I have an open bug in UWSGI as well, https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/issues/958

Comment: @KevinDolan That's frustrating. When a bug is so common that it affects a large portion of your userbase... *sigh*

Comment: @KevinDolan Jani from Google here: issue #12123 has been re-opened, and we're planning to return to the previous behavior of using relative paths in SDK 1.9.24.